# Can't use string ("test_value") as a HASH ref while "strict refs" in use at main.pl line 23

Tags: regex, perl-hash

Can't use string ("test_value") as a HASH ref while "strict refs" in use at main.pl line 23.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $config = {'%test_value' => {'value' => '1'}};
    
my $args = 'test_value';    

print $$config{%$args}{'value'};
```

I'm trying to use the variable/argument for hash reference

Comment: `my $args = '%test_value';`
`print $config->{$args}{'value'};`

Comment: @Grobu do you mind writing this as an answer, so the OP can accept it and we can close the question?

Comment: @bfontaine yes, and sorry for leaving this question without a proper answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
my $config = {'%test_value' => {'value' => '1'}};
```

The `$config` variable contains a reference to an anonymous hash, which also contains a reference to another anonymous hash :

```
$config --> anonymous_hash1:
              key   =   "%test_value"
              value --> anonymous_hash2:
                          key   = "value"
                          value = "1"
```

To de-refence such a variable, you can do:

```
print $$config{'%test_value'}, "\n";
```

or (using the arrow operator):

```
print $config->{'%test_value'}, "\n";
```

This should print something like `HASH(0x4151e59ab6b7)` (type of data structure and memory address of *second anonymous hash*).

You can chain the dereferencing syntax to access embedded data:

```
print $$config{'%test_value'}{'value'}, "\n";
```

or, with arrow operator:

```
print $config->{'%test_value'}->{'value'}, "\n";
```

---

When you write

```
my $args = 'test_value';    

print $$config{%$args}{'value'};
```

... the `%$args` expression is *not equivalent* to the '%test_value' key. The key you defined was of type string, and `%$args` evaluates to something completely different.  Unquoted "%" symbol has a special meaning in Perl syntax, it is known as a sigil, and it introduces "hash context" to the following variable name / reference.

For example, if you take the following declarations:

```
my %my_hash = ( foo    => 'bar',
                hello  => 'world',
                number => 42 );

my $hash_ref = \%my_hash;
```

`$my_hash{'foo'}` and `$$hash_ref{'foo'}` would both return 'bar'.

`$my_hash{'foo'}` can be understood as "I need to access a **scalar value** (because of the leading `$` sigil) stored in key "foo" of hash "my_hash".  Similarly, `$$hash_ref{'foo'}` means "I need to access a scalar value stored in key "foo" of the hash referenced by variable `$hash_ref`.  The hash sigil (`%`), contrary to the scalar one (`$`), allows to operate on the whole hash data structure, e.g. you can use it with the `delete`, `exists`, `each`, `keys` and `values` functions, which expect a hash argument.

Example:

```
foreach (keys %my_hash) { print "my_hash{$_} = $my_hash{$_}\n"; }
```

will produce:

```
my_hash{hello} = world
my_hash{number} = 42
my_hash{foo} = bar
```

... and `foreach (keys %$hash_ref) ...` will produce the same output!

So when you wrote `%$args`, Perl probably understood it as "consider the hash data structure referenced by variable `$args`", but `$args` contained a string, not a hash reference.

---

This is a complex topic and my understanding of it is probably very superficial and naive.  See https://perldoc.perl.org/perlref and https://perldoc.perl.org/perlreftut for authoritative documentation.

Hope that helped ^^